Delphi Project export table size exceeds limit of 65536 after upgrade to Delphi 12.1
I'm currently facing a challenging issue after upgrading our project from Delphi 10.2 to 12.1. Our project is quite large, spanning over 25 years, and has recently undergone significant component upgrades.
Project background

Original Delphi version: 10.2
Upgraded Delphi version: 12.1 (Athens)
Components upgraded: all necessary components were updated to their latest versions compatible with Delphi 12.1.

After successfully upgrading the components and attempting to build the project, we encountered the following compiler error:

[dcc32 Error] E2621 Export table in output file too large: exceeds 65536 limits

This issue suggests that the export table size has exceeded the permissible limit. We previously had the same issue related to the large export table but managed to keep it within limits. However, the current situation is more complex due to the large number of upgraded components and potential changes in how exports are managed in Delphi 12.1.
Actions taken

Map file analysis:

Generated detailed map files to analyze exported symbols.
Compared the map files from Delphi 10.2 and Delphi 12.1 builds.


CFF Explorer:

Attempted to use CFF Explorer to view the export table size directly but could not proceed as the project build fails.



Question

How can I determine the current number of exports to understand how far above the limit we are?

Any insights or strategies to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Are we talking here about a library project or an application project? If we are talkig here about an application then I'm wondering why do you even need so many exports in the first place. If we are talking about a library then you might want to consider splitting this one library into two separate libraries in order to reduce the number of exports per library.

@SilverWarior It's a core application surrounded by 42 different modules. Unfortunately, I joined the team a bit too late, as the original design and development teams have long since parted ways. We had been managing the separation/splitting of the modules in our daily tasks (we were already close to the table limit before the upgrade), but we are now facing this issue post-upgrade.

Most projects compile more than one file - what specific type of file is it failing on. If it's a package then as mentioned in the first results on Google for the error move some used units into the requires section. See the first tips and tricks at https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/delphi-in-a/1565926595/re272.html for why it might help.
